# Xamarin UDP iOS crashing, but working on Android - Special permissions?

Tags: ios, xamarin, udp

I am using this example from Microsoft as the basics for UDP transfer using Xamarin, I have it working on Android with no problems but on iOS is crashing on the udpClient.Close().

Do you have to setup any special permissions on iOS to use UDP?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: it would be very helpful to know what exception is causing the crash

Comment: I am using a try & catch and it just crashing out // brendon error state -> code changed
            Debug.WriteLine("Debug: close -> updClient -> " + udpClient);
            try
            {
                udpClient.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Debug: UDP Close error" + udpClient);
            }

Comment: do the logs show anything?  Have you tried a crash reporting tool like appcenter.ms?

Comment: Good point, I removed the catch and crashes with the error "system.nullreferenceException" has been thrown" Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Does that been the UDP has lost it's connection?

Comment: no idea.  Is it your code causing the null ref, or something further down the stack?

Comment: udpClient = new UdpClient(11000); looks like this is returning a null, is there something in the iOS or permissions which could block the connection?

Answer (score 0):

What we found iOS takes longer to process UDP packets, compared to Android so when we try a transfer using await/aync the process was never finishing before we requested another the UDP transfer. As the await/async had not opened a UDP channel, when we came to close it would generate an expectation.